# User settings' persistence in NPAPI?

Tags: firefox, plugins, npapi, npruntime

I was wondering, if there's anything in NPAPI, which supports reading/writing user settings? Currently I use XPCOM, but I want to get rid of this code in order to support other browsers than Firefox.
I understand I can just read/write the file system (or registry on Windows) directly, but I want to explore other options - allowing the user edit these settings from the browser (e.g. about:config in FF) is, arguably, a better user experience than to direct him to edit some custom-made config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in NPAPI.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac plugins that need preferences sometimes ship a system preference pane with the plugin (and have a context menu item to open that pref pane), so that users have a UI for editing prefs. If there's not something similar for Windows and Linux you could always ship a small app that edits the prefs.